I want to write a script that simultaneously renders what's on my webcam to a window on my screen and records a video
I have tried a combination of:

v4l2loopback
ffmpeg
mpv

But either the web-cam view, or the web-cam record works, but never both together.
Can anyone provide a script that achieves this?
This is what I've tried so far:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

# This needs the video loopback module to be installed.
# sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=10 card_label="VirtualCam" exclusive_caps=1

# use `pw-cli list-objects | grep node.name` to get the audio device
AUDIO_DEVICE="alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo"
VIDEO_DEVICE="/dev/video0"
VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE="/dev/video10"

read -p "Enter a name for the video: " VIDEO_NAME

if [ -z "$VIDEO_NAME" ]; then
    VIDEO_NAME="unnamed_video"
fi

OUTPUT_FILE="$HOME/videos/${VIDEO_NAME}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).mkv"

trap 'echo "Stopping recording..."; pkill -P $$; exit 0' SIGINT

ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i "$VIDEO_DEVICE" \
    -f v4l2 -video_size 640x480 -i "$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE" &

sleep 2

# Start displaying the virtual webcam feed with mpv
mpv --no-osc \
    --no-input-default-bindings \
    --profile=low-latency \
    --geometry=50%:50% \
    --autofit=100% \
    --input-conf=/dev/null \
    --title='WebcamDisplay' \
    --framedrop=no \
    --vf=scale=640:-1 \
    --vo=vaapi \
    "$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE" &

# Start recording from the virtual device with ffmpeg
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i "$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE" \
    -f pulse -i "$AUDIO_DEVICE" \
    -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 48000 \
    "$OUTPUT_FILE"

# Stop all processes when done
pkill ffmpeg
pkill mpv


This is my loopback setup:
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
VirtualCam (platform:v4l2loopback-010):
        /dev/video10

Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate (usb-0000:00:14.0-12):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
        /dev/media0





Unless the writing of the script is a necessary part of your requirement have you considered just using a suite like OBS?

OBS seems very heavy duty for the relatively simple thing I want to do. There is also a Linux app called "Cheese" which would do the job, but I really just want to keep this really minimal.

You're 90% there. Instead of trying to read the same camera device (virtual or not), simply add another output to your first ffmpeg invocation.
Ffmeg's options are generally in the format:

ffmpeg {general and input options} {options for the first output} first output specification {options for the second output} second output specification

So, translating this to your use case, you'd want something like
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0   -f v4fl2 /dev/video10   -c:v libx264  out.mkv
#      | input opt+spec      | | output 1: no -i !!  |  |  output 2         |

You can also bring in your audio stream at the same point; that's where -map in ffmpeg is handy: you can map around multiple input and output destinations.

you lost me with the -map stuff....

@Brad in your script, in your second ffmpeg invocation you bring in the audio stream, right? You can also do that in what I describe above, as second input (-f pulse -i…) stream. But you need to tell ffmpeg that audio only goes to the output .mkv, and not to the outputl v4l2 device.

Erm... I think I understand that conceptually but I don't understand how -map does this. Is there a specific invocation or switch that you are saying I should be applying in this context. Sorry if I'm being slow, but I am a complete n00b with ffmpeg. :exploding_head:

check out man ffmpeg. It has nice ascii art pictures! https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs might help, as well.

:) -- I was just waiting for the RTFM... Ok, cool -- I'll go have a dig through it all. It's true I'm being a bit lazy here, so fair point...

what's "RTFM" about "here's exactly what you need to do"????

man ffmpeg == "RTFM".  I appreciate your help @Marcus -- I'll go figure out the this -map stuff to get this working.

+1 on the TRAC link -- the FFmpeg wiki pages are super helpful with learning how to use some of the less obvious options.

So, after reading the man page, and the trac link, I really didn't understand much of anything. So, out of desperation I resorted to chat GPT, which suggested this:
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i "$VIDEO_DEVICE" \        -f pulse -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo \        -c:v copy -c:a aac -f v4l2 "$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE" \        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac "$OUTPUT_FILE" &
This doesn't work either. So I am still stumped.

As @marcus-müller pointed out (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/783282/663280) you can use ffmpeg to write the output file and stream to the loopback device. Modify the first call to ffmpeg  to look (similar) to:
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 30 -video_size 640x480 -input_format mjpeg -i "$VIDEO_DEVICE" \
    -f pulse -i "$AUDIO_DEVICE" \
    -c:v copy -f v4l2 "$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE" \
    -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 48000 \
    "$OUTPUT_FILE" &

Relative to your original call we have:

Added -input_format mjpeg to the 1st line as this is what most (USB) webcams will use for higher resolution and higher frame rate (if it uses something else like H264, by all means, specify here).
Inserted -f pulse -i "$AUDIO_DEVICE" after the 1st line to pull in the audio input.
Opted to 'passthrough' video to the loopback device via -c:v copy before the device (outfile).
Inserted the lines for output to disk from your original 2nd call to ffmpeg.

Note: using codec is set to H264 for the output to disk by -c:v option prior to the filename (outfile).



We also need to help mpv understand the loopback device. I found the following resource: https://github-wiki-see.page/m/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/Video4Linux2-Input.
We can easily modify your call to mpv to get the correct result:
# Start displaying the virtual webcam feed with mpv
mpv --no-osc \
    --no-input-default-bindings \
    --profile=low-latency \
    --untimed \
    --geometry=50%:50% \
    --autofit=100% \
    --input-conf=/dev/null \
    --title='WebcamDisplay' \
    --framedrop=no \
    --vf=scale=640:-1 \
    --vo=vaapi \
    "av://v4l2:$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE"

Compared to your original call:

We've added --untimed - which can be useful for MJPEG streams (see man mpv).
We've modified the filename to include the prefix av://v4l2: (again, most details are available in man mpv).
It no longer needs to be detached via &.

The second invocation of ffmpeg should be deleted.
All in all:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

# This needs the video loopback module to be installed.
# sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=10 card_label="VirtualCam" exclusive_caps=1

# use `pw-cli list-objects | grep node.name` to get the audio device
AUDIO_DEVICE="alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo"
VIDEO_DEVICE="/dev/video0"
VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE="/dev/video10"

read -p "Enter a name for the video: " VIDEO_NAME

if [ -z "$VIDEO_NAME" ]; then
    VIDEO_NAME="unnamed_video"
fi

OUTPUT_FILE="$HOME/videos/${VIDEO_NAME}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).mkv"

trap 'echo "Stopping recording..."; pkill -P $$; exit 0' SIGINT

ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 30 -video_size 640x480 -input_format mjpeg -i "$VIDEO_DEVICE" \
    -f pulse -i "$AUDIO_DEVICE" \
    -c:v copy -f v4l2 "$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE" \
    -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 48000 \
    "$OUTPUT_FILE" &

sleep 2

# Start displaying the virtual webcam feed with mpv
mpv --no-osc \
    --no-input-default-bindings \
    --profile=low-latency \
    --untimed \
    --geometry=50%:50% \
    --autofit=100% \
    --input-conf=/dev/null \
    --title='WebcamDisplay' \
    --framedrop=no \
    --vf=scale=640:-1 \
    --vo=vaapi \
    "av://v4l2:$VIRTUAL_VIDEO_DEVICE"

# Stop all processes when done
pkill ffmpeg
pkill mpv

